# How can I assign data from Http response in const Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, frontend

My goal is to ultimately create add a shopping cart functionality using context API. In order to do so I need to get the products from my database and store it in an array.

Currently, the challenge I'm facing is how to retrieve the data from the axios response and store it in a variable that will be passed on within a const component. Apparently, the issue is that the variable gets passed to the child before the Axios response is complete. [image]

I tried using the `await` keyword, but got an error regarding not being in an `async` function. Hence, I tried plugging the `async` keyword but that didn't work as it yielded errors.

I was able to retrieve data from axios within class components with success, however, I am unable to do so in these `const`.

Here is my code:

**Context.js**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
import React from "react";
import ProductService from "../services/ProductService";
import { cartReducer } from "./Reducers";

const Cart = createContext();
const Context = ({ children }) => {
  let products = [];

  console.log("part1", products);

  ProductService.getAllProducts().then((res) => {
    products = res.data; //Also tried setState({ products : res.data})
    console.log("response: ", products);
  });

  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(cartReducer, {
    products: products,
    cart: [],
  });

  return <Cart.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>{children}</Cart.Provider>;
};

export const CartState = () => {
  return useContext(Cart);
};

export default Context;
```

**ProductService.js**

```
import axios from "axios";

const PRODUCT_BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/";

class ProductService {
  getAllProducts() {
    return axios.get(PRODUCT_BASE_URL + "products");
  }
  getProductsByCategory(category) {
    return axios.get(PRODUCT_BASE_URL + "products/" + category);
  }

  getProductById(id) {
    return axios.get(PRODUCT_BASE_URL + "product/" + id);
  }
}
export default new ProductService();
```

**Reducers.js**

```
export const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

**HomeComponenet.jsx**

```
import React from "react";
import SlideShowComponent from "./SlideShowComponent";
import HomeCategoriesComponent from "./HomeCategoriesComponent";
import FeaturedProductsComponent from "./FeaturedProductsComponent";
import { CartState } from "../context/Context";
// class HomeComponent extends React.Component
function HomeComponent() {
  const { state } = CartState();
  console.log("Cart Inside the Home Component: ", state);
  return (
    <>
      <SlideShowComponent />
      <div>
        <HomeCategoriesComponent />
      </div>
      <div>
        <FeaturedProductsComponent />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default HomeComponent;
```

Comment: I tried these things : https://pretagteam.com/question/how-to-assign-data-to-a-variable-from-axios-get-response

Comment: Please put all information in your question post, not in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I've created a fixed example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jqtcia?file=src/Context.js

You are correct, you need to `await` the result from axios. In React, we use the [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook for things with side effects or that should not be done as part of the render. Renders in react should be non blocking, that is they should not be dependent on things like data fetching.

A simple example of this would be if we needed it in local state. This example renders without the data, then re-renders once the data is available.

```js
const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
useEffect(async () => {
    const { data } = await ProductService.getAllProducts();
    setProducts(data);
}, []);
return <div>{products.length > 0 ? `${products.length} products` : 'Loading...'</div>
```

**NOTE:** the `, []);` means that this will fire once, when the first render happens.

This fixes the first part of your problem, getting the result out of the request/axios.

However, the second part and most important part is that you weren't using this value. You were attempting to insert the result as part of the initial state, but this was empty by the time it was created. As you are using reducers ([useReducer](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer)), this means you need to dispatch an action for each event and handle all the relevant events to data fetching in the reducer. That means, you should need to be able to handle:

1. Some data is in a loading state (e.g., pagination or first load)
2. The data failed to load
3. The data is partially loaded
4. The data has fully loaded

I've created a minimal happy example (there is no pagination and data fetching always succeeds):

**Context.js**

```js
  useEffect(async () => {
    const { data: loadedProducts } = await ProductService.getAllProducts();
    console.log('response: ', JSON.stringify(loadedProducts));
    dispatch({ type: 'PRODUCTS_LOADED', products: loadedProducts });
    console.log(state);
  }, []);
```

**Reducers.js**

```js
export const cartReducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PRODUCTS_LOADED':
      const newState = { ...state, products: action.products };
      console.log(newState);
      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

In fact, if you'd done this with your original code, it would've worked:

```js
ProductService.getAllProducts().then((res) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'PRODUCTS_LOADED', products : res.data});
    console.log("response: ", products);
  });
```

However, this has a different bug: It will refetch the data and then dispatch the event each time Context.js is re-rendered.

---

Since you've asked for more information in your comment, I'll provide it here (comments were not big enough).
I've linked the relevant API documentation for the hooks above, these provide pretty good information. React does a pretty good job of explaining the what, and why of these hooks (and the library itself). Seriously, if you haven't read their [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html), you should do so.

Additional resources:

[What, when and how to use useEffect](https://medium.com/@dev_abhi/useeffect-what-when-and-how-95045bcf0f32) - In short, if you have something to do that isn't rendering such as data fetching, it's a side-effect and should be in a `useEffect`.

[What is a reducer in JavaScript/React/Redux](https://www.robinwieruch.de/javascript-reducer/) - Reducers are a pattern to make shared state easier to manage and test. The basic idea is that you define a `reducer`, which takes an initial state and an event/action, and produces a new state. The key idea is that there must be no side-effects, the same action and state will always produce the same result, no matter the date/time, network state, etc, etc. This makes testing and reasoning about things easier, but at the cost of a more complex state management.

However, something important that I ignored in your original question is that you are kind of reinventing the wheel here. There is already a library that will centralise your state and make it available via context, it's the library that originally invented reducers: [redux](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started). I'm guessing you have read something like [this article about using context instead of redux](https://auth0.com/blog/starting-a-new-app-with-redux-consider-context-api-first/), however the advantage of redux for you is that there is a litany of documentation about how to use it and solve these problems.

My recommendation for you is to make sure [you need/want redux/reducers](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367). It has it's value and I personally love the pattern but if you are just getting started on React, you would be better off just using `useState` in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was stuck trying to do this for a while. Stackoverflow is amazing. Do you have any resources that talk about this more in depth?

Comment: I've added some more resources and information @creativeAxe.

Comment: Also, glad I could help :)